# R markdown not knitting the equations

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown

I am using R markdown to knit a paper of mine, and R markdown does not knit

```
\begin{equation} 
  f\left(k\right) = \binom{n}{k} p^k\left(1-p\right)^{n-k}
  (\#eq:binom)
\end{equation}
```

it would knit
`$\phi _ { k }$`.

In conclusion, it does not recognize `\begin..\end`

any ideas? Thank you!

I am not getting any error messages, and the code used to work in rnw file.

Comment: A few more details would help. `Rnw` files are essentially LaTeX files with some R code blocks, while `Rmd` R markdown files are markdown files with some R code blocks. Markdown knows about some equation stuff, but it isn't LaTeX and you can't throw any old LaTeX into a markdown file and have it work. It sounds like you were using Rnw, and now you switched to Rmd, is that right?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: It may work if you replace your `\begin{equation}` and `\end{equation}` with `$$` if you're using regular Rmarkdown - though I don't think the equation labeling will work that way. [If you switch to bookdown](https://rmd4sci.njtierney.com/captioning-and-referencing-equations.html) and use the `bookdown::html_document2` output, this code might work.

Comment: @GregorThomas Thanks for your response. I agree, that problem occurs when I switched from rnw to rmd, and it gave me problems. However, I have seen other people in their code using the begin end thing so I thought it should work

Comment: It would help if you would make your example reproducible by at least sharing your YAML header. Whether you're knitting to html or PDF or `html_document2` etc. can also make a difference.